# Return course order with class prerequisites

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Question:
Given Input: Courses and their dependencies(prerequisites)
such as A < B; A < C; B < D; C < D return course order in the order a student can take. i.e answer should return A, B, C, D or A, C, B, D

I solved the problem, but the running time is very slow, I cannot seem to figure out how to improve my algorithm. FYI: This isn't for schoolwork or project, just curious.

Answer:

```
  function getCourseOrder(input) {
  let result = [];

  while(Object.keys(input).length !== 0){
    for (let item in input) {
        let depencies = input[item];

        if (!depencies || depencies.length === 0) {
          delete input[item];
          result.push(item);
          continue;
        }

      let hasAlreadyTakenClasses = depencies.every((currentValue) => {
        return result.indexOf(currentValue) > -1;
      })

      if (hasAlreadyTakenClasses) {
        delete input[item];
        result.push(item);
      }

    }
  }

  return result;
}

var input =  {a: [], b: ['a'], c: ['a'], d:['c','b'] }
```

Comment: Find a topological order.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, the problem you are trying to solve is an instance of the more general problem of finding a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of a particular set.
In your case, the ordering is given by the *"being a prerequisite of"* relation.
At the implementational level, switching your dictionary with an adjacency matrix *may* improve the runtime.